# CSS sprite image + background-repeat a part of it

Tags: css, sprite, background-position, background-repeat

Can I repeat a **part** of an image [which it's in a CSS sprite image] in the background ?!

like for example :

> background-position : -13px top ;
>     background-repeat : repeat-y ;

because I got the whole sprite image repeated ...

Answer (score 10):

If you place your images side by side in a really wide sprite you'll be able to use repeat-y. If you need to use repeat-x you can place the images in the sprite above each other.

Comment: what do you mean by "wide" in pixels ?!

Comment: @Waseem assuming you have 20 images in the sprite each with a 100px width, then the sprite would be 200px wide.

Comment: @Waseem - here is a link to help support @Gareth's explanation -> [CSS background-repeat](http://www.phpied.com/background-repeat-and-css-sprites/)